# Validation not working - param is missing or the value is empty carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, delayed-job

I have search for my problem but I can't found any solution.

My model `home` with attributes such as : `title`, `logo`, `description`, `keywords`.

I'm using carrierwave + delayed job for upload a `logo`, the upload is works (create & update) but when file / input file is empty I got this error :

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in SettingsController#home_update_b
param is missing or the value is empty: home

Extracted source (around line #99): 

  def home_update_b_params
      params.require(:home).permit(:logo)
  end
end
```

SettingsController

```
def index
 ## get one record without params
 @home = Home.take 
end

def home_update_b
  @home = Home.find(params[:id])
   if @home.update(home_update_b_params)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to setting_home_path, :notice => "Logo successfully updated" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      end 
   else
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { 
           flash[:alert] = "There's Something Wrong"
           render :action => :home
      }
      format.json { render json: @home.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end

private

def home_update_b_params
 params.require(:home).permit(:logo)
end
```

I'm sure on `home` model have validate

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
    after_save :enqueue

    validates_presence_of :logo
end
```

form

```
<%= form_for(@home, :url => logo_update_path(@home), :html => { :class => "form-horizontal", :role => "form", :method => :put}) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :logo, "Logo", :class => 'col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right ace-file-input' %>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= f.file_field :logo, "data-file-input" => "easy" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix form-actions">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

stack trace

```
Processing by SettingsController#home_update_b as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"gmXtbe31vfSPqM1N5taM1ge92nRvr
SpY91Y8vAlEBmc=", "commit"=>"Update Home", "id"=>"2"}
  ←[1m←[36mHome Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT  "homes".* FROM "homes"  WHERE "hom
es"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 2]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: home
):
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:99:in `home_update_b_params'
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:60:in `home_update_b'
```

When I add another attribute to form (e.g `title`), input file still empty and it's works to update, but validation not works for input file is empty.

FYI Rails 4.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Why do you use `button_tag` instead of `f.submit` or `f.button`?

Comment: Can I use icon (`<i>` tag) with `f.submit` ? I think there is no reason for my problem because I'm use that for new form and it's works. Also use `f.button` still error.

Comment: You can with `f.button` like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I know, but my problem isn't about button/submit. My problem is `validates_of_preference` is not working

Comment: So edit your question. Because right now the error you pasted points to the problem with your form button.

Comment: Can you show me where the error point to with button? I think my question and the error point to validation is not working.

Comment: So you're wrong. The error is about wrong params passed into controller, which is linked directly with your form.

Comment: When input file not empty and it's successfully uploaded (use button_tag / f.button), but when input file is empty, I got that error. So, why when file is empty validation not works and show the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are accepting any type of file from the user using an input type of "file" and the user doesn't select it, you won't get a key for that field in the parameter hash.

In your case, you are accepting only a logo from the user, and if it's empty, the **home** key doesn't exist in your parameter hash, thus the [`require()`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) method throws an exception because it didn't find the specified key.

Instead of `require()` you can use the [`fetch()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) method which can return an empty hash as default value if the specified key is not found. Like this:

```
params.fetch(:home, {}).permit(:logo)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just ran into the same problem.